# I can't start spyder in Anaconda after I carelessly delete ".spyder" and ".matplotlib" folders. Error is "No Qt platform plugin could be initialized"

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I initially want to update my spyder edition to 5.4.3, after I update it, several issues appearanced. I firstly used some method given by other online platforms that delete ".spyder-py3" and ".matplotlib" folders then restart spyder. However, I failed to start and the error occured "No Qt platform plugin could be initialized, available platform plugin are minimal, offscreen. webgl, windows." Moreover, I can't find origin ".spyder" folders in my recycle bin.

I have tried to reinstalling spyder in anaconda, but the error still exist. What should I do to tackle this error?

Comment: I try to copy all items in PyQt5\Qt5\bin into PyQt5_tools\Qt5\bin, but an error occuerd : Exit code: 3221226505

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.